# Using a typedefed default type for template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I have a class where I want the template parameter B to have a default type. The problem is that the default type is a complicated expression depending also on the type of A.

The following code illustrates the situation but does obviously not compile, because *defaultB* type is not know inside the template expression.

```
template<class A, class B = defaultB>
class Foo{

   typedef A::Bar Bar;
   typedef Bar::Ex defaultB;


};
```

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem properly?

Comment: Isn't that simpler -> `template <class A, class B = A::Bar::Ex>`?

Comment: @myaut

Thank you! Well the above example is an extreme simplified version of the situation, the problem is that A::Bar::Ex is in fact a very complicated expression.

Answer (score 3):

You could maintain a namespace of defaults like this:

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename A>
    using defaultB = typename A::Bar::Ex;
}

template<class A, class B = typename detail::defaultB<A>>
class Foo{
};
```

This lets you have as complex expressions as you like in your `detail` namespace without making the `Foo` declaration ugly.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to TartanLlama's excellent suggestion is to maintain a dummy type hierarchy to lift up the `typedef`'s into scope:

```
template<class A> 
struct _Foo {
    typedef typename A::Bar Bar;
    typedef typename Bar::Ex defaultB;
};

template<class A,class B=typename _Foo<A>::defaultB>
struct Foo : _Foo<A> {
};
```