# avoid duplicated code : typedef/using a template class that has default parameter (C++14)

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, typedef, maintainability

How to define an alias name of a template class that has default template parameter without code duplication?

Does C++14 improve it in some ways?

In a real case, it really causes maintainability problem.   ([demo](http://ideone.com/0XZViK))

```
class B{};
template<class T1,class T2,class T3=B>class E{};   //<- "class T3=B"
//^ library

//v user
class C{};
template<class T1,class T3=B> using F=E<T1,C,T3>;  //<- "class T3=B" is duplicated
int main() {
    F<B> f1;
    F<B,C> f2;
    return 0;
}
```

### **Workaround**

In old C++, there is no elegant solution.
Here is the best workaround, modified from [Using a typedefed default type for template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671388/using-a-typedefed-default-type-for-template-parameter) :-

```
class B{};
using E_T3_default=B;
template<class T1,class T2,class T3=E_T3_default>class E{}; //<-
//^ library

//v user
class C{};
template<class T1,class T3=E_T3_default> using F=E<T1,C,T3>;  //<-
```

### **My dream**

I hope for something like:-

```
template<class T1,class T3> using F=E<T1,C,T3>;
```

and `F<B>` will be expanded to `E<B,C,B(default)>` automatically (not compile error).

Comment: Do you mean that `F<B>` aliases `E<B, C, B>`?

Comment: @Quentin  Ops!  Yes. I will edit it.  Thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a parameter pack:

```
template <class T1, class... T3>
using F = E<T1, C, T3...>;
```

... to directly forward zero or one argument to `E`.

Comment: So smart as always, sir Quentin.   .... I feel that I have encountered this technique before.  It is shameful that I didn't consider about it.  C++ is a very large language.

Comment: Oh stop it, you :p